# how can I use an infix expression in a case statement in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I want to compare two binary logic vectors A, and B. However my code won't compile and I am not sure why I am not allowed to use comparison statements here. can anyone help me? My problem is that I am new to VHDL  and I need some tips

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

--entity declaration of IC74x85 with port definitions
entity IC74x85 is
port(    A : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  --input A is a 4 bit binary number
     B : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  --input B is a 4 bit binary number
     ALTBOUT : out std_logic;   -- A < B
     AEQBOUT : out std_logic;   -- A = B
     AGTBOUT : out std_logic    -- A > B
);
end IC74x85;

--architecture of entity
architecture IC74x85_arch of IC74x85 is

begin
process(A,B)
begin
    case A is
     when (A < B) => ALTBOUT <= '1';
     when (A > B) => AGTBOUT <= '1';
     when (A = B) => AEQBOUT <= '1';
     when others => ALTBOUT, AGTBOUT, AEQBOUT <= '0';
     end case;
end process;
end IC74x85_arch;
```

** Error: C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Ass1/case signal assignment.vhd(21): Type error resolving infix expression "<" as type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR.

** Error: C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Ass1/case signal assignment.vhd(21): Choice in CASE statement alternative must be locally static.

** Error: C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Ass1/case signal assignment.vhd(22): Type error resolving infix expression ">" as type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR.

** Error: C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Ass1/case signal assignment.vhd(22): Choice in CASE statement alternative must be locally static.

** Error: C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Ass1/case signal assignment.vhd(23): Type error resolving infix expression "=" as type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR.

** Error: C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Ass1/case signal assignment.vhd(23): Choice in CASE statement alternative must be locally static.

** Error: C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Ass1/case signal assignment.vhd(24): near ",": expecting <= or :=

Comment: Use an [If statement](http://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-if-statement.html)

Comment: how do I use the if statement inside a case statement?

Comment: Your case statement can be replaced entirely by a sequence of `if`, `elseif`, and `else` statements.

Comment: yes I know that, but how do I do it with a case statement?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do cannot be accomplished with a case statement, but you can simply write it as an if-then-else. Also, you can't use comparison operations like `<` and `>` on std_logic_vectors -- this is something that takes numeric interpretation, so you need to use the `signed` or `unsigned` types depending on what kind of numbers you have:

First, include `ieee.numeric_std.all`:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

Then cast the data types correctly for your comparisons:

```
process(A,B)
begin
     if    signed(A) < signed(B) then ALTBOUT <= '1'; 
     elsif signed(A) > signed(B) then AGTBOUT <= '1';
     else  signed(A) = signed(B) then AEQBOUT <= '1';
     else ALTBOUT <=0; AGTBOUT <=0; AEQBOUT <= '0';
     end if;
end process;
```

Comment: you can definitely use a VHDL comparison operator on one dimensional arrays. I just need to get it to work in a case statement

Comment: @Steven: you can't do comparisons on std_logic_vectors, unless you include another package which defines how to interpret the bits.  `ieee.std_logic_arith` is one common, but [technically shouldn't be used,](http://parallelpoints.com/numbers-in-vhdl/) package.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a case statement to do this.  Your error messages say why:

> Type error resolving infix expression "<" as type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR.

You are asking the compiler to choose a case based on the value of `A`. The code you have written is asking the compiler to compare `A` (an slv) with `A<B` which is a boolean.  Clearly, that won't ever work.

Answer (score 0):

As answered before, this is a job for the `if-elsif-else` statements and the `signed` data type.

However, if for some reason you really wanted to this with a `case` statement -- as in:  "Hey, Joe I'll give you a big bag of money if your can write this in VHDL using a `case` statement and no `if-elsif-else` statements."  It can be done.  Joe Engineer would concatenate the `A` and `B` together (it is assumed `A` and `B` are 4-bits wide) into an 8-bit `std_logic_vector`, called `C`.  Then Joe would write a `case` with `C` and have 256 `when` statements  -- each `when` would set `ALTBOUT`, `AGTBOUT`, and `AEQBOUT` to the correct value for each 8-bit pattern.

Of course, this is a silly way to do this (unless someone is going to give you a big bag of money :-) !

BTW: What wjl gave:

```
process(A,B)
begin
     if    signed(A) < signed(B) then ALTBOUT <= '1'; 
     elsif signed(A) > signed(B) then AGTBOUT <= '1';
     elsif signed(A) = signed(B) then AEQBOUT <= '1';
     else ALTBOUT <=0; AGTBOUT <=0; AEQBOUT <= '0';
     end if;
end process;
```

(Sorry, I cannot leave comments to answers, yet, or I would comment on mjl's answer) can be improved (beyond the inferred latch issue): There is no reason to test for `A==B`.  If `NOT (A<B)` and `NOT (A>B)` then `A` must equal `B`.

```
process(A,B)
begin
     ALTBOUT <=0; AGTBOUT <=0; AEQBOUT <= '0';
     if    signed(A) < signed(B) then ALTBOUT <= '1'; 
     elsif signed(A) > signed(B) then AGTBOUT <= '1';
     else                             AEQBOUT <= '1';
     end if;
end process;
```